# node-gyp Err: Cannot find module - windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I installed node-gyp globally and its saved at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp`

when I run: `$ node-gyp` in command-prompt, I get this error

```
if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"  )  else (node ""  )
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

`

Key part here is `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js` 
when it should be looking at `C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js`

Python version `Python 2.7.14`

Windows Build tools have been installed too.

Node version `v8.9.4`

User Variables:

[image: User Variables]

[image: System Variables]

Comment: Go to C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node_modules, delete the node-gyp folder. Then try re-install it. It might be corrupted.

Comment: re-install **node-gyp** using _npm install -g node-gyp_

Comment: @hashris : There's no `node_modules` folder inside `npm\node_modules\`. @lyes : I've retried again, but its still looking for it in a directory which doesn't exist. maybe issue with my environment variables?

Comment: You can install [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15), make sure to select C++ tools, Windows 10 SDK and MSBuild and your set.

Comment: This is what worked. Thankyou!